# How to install TensorFlow 2.X on Mac OS (Big Sur, Catalina, Mojave) without Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

After an OS update, I spent several hours installing Tensorflow 2.X on my Mac laptop running OS X Catalina (same problem with Big Sur or Mojave) but WITHOUT ANACONDA. I searched a lot finding only bits of the answer and finally found a solution that I would like to share to help other people.

I've got mainly two kind of problems: 1) “Operation not permitted” caused by zealous strengthening of security on the new Mac OS and 2) problem installing TensorFlow 2.X of the kind “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'“ caused by messy paths to Python libraries.

Answer (score 1):

1. First correct “Operation not permitted” by granting Terminal full disk access using “Security & Privacy” control panel in the system preferences. Find the details [here](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/).
2. Install TensorFlow 2.X on your Mac without using Anaconda (if that's what you want).
   [inspiration from](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/09/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-0-on-macos/)

2.1) Be sure to have XCode and its command line tools and pip3 installed

2.2) Install Python 3.8 using Brew (I think 3.9 is not compatible yet with TensorFlow)

```
> brew install python@3.8
> brew link --force python@3.8
```

2.3) Add symbolic link

```
> ln -s /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

2.4) Add PATH and compiler flags in the .zshrc file (or .bash_profile)

```
> echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc
> echo 'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/lib/pkgconfig"' >> ~/.zshrc
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 
> source .zshrc
```

2.5) Install cmake

```
> brew install cmake pkg-config wget
```

2.6) Install TensorFlow 2.X

```
> sudo pip3 install tensorflow
```