# How to install: Python 3.8 (required to be downloaded from Xcode Command Line Tools for M1 Macs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am trying to install TensorFlow on my M1 Mac. The readme for apple's [tensorflow_macos repo](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) specifies installing python 3.8 using Xcode Command Line Tools. I currently have the latest version of Xcode Command Line Tools installed but am lost on how to install python 3.8 using those tools. If anyone has any guidance I would be extremely grateful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This post may be useful and should give you what you need:

[How to install TensorFlow 2.X on Mac OS (Big Sur, Catalina, Mojave) without Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712926/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-x-on-mac-os-big-sur-catalina-mojave-without-anac)

Also you can ensure that you have commandline tools installed by doing this from a terminal window:

xcode-select --install

Finally, be sure you create a virtual environment to work in - the post above should help - this will allow you to install various versions of python, etc without clobbering system installed versions. Good luck